# How to get the whole list of rally model type names?

Tags: rally

I'm a newbee working on rally custom pages and have a question about the rally model type.

For example, when setting a storeConfig like below:

```
storeConfig : {
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'UserStory'
}
```

where is the model type name from? how to get the full list of the valid model type names?

I have tried to go through the online docs but couldn't find any information about this. Also it seems that "User story" is also a valid model name.

In the Web Services API Documentation, it seems that HierarchicalRequirment is for user story. but I couldn't find any information about this in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models should map to [their API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp) - however, one trick you can use is to open your console when logged into the Rally site. Once you get to any of their newer pages, you should be able to see all the Models that are loaded up:

```
for (model in Rally.data.wsapi.ModelFactory._modelCache) console.log(model);
```

which gives me something like:

```
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.testcasestep
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.testcase
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitemfeature
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.userprofile
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.buildmetric
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.conversationpost
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.defect
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.defectsuite
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.milestone
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.projectpermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.portfolioiteminitiative
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.user
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.artifactnotification
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.testset
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.tag
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.workspacepermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.scmrepository
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.preference
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitemtheme
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.revision
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.changeset
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.iteration
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.change
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.workspaceconfiguration
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.attachment
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.scopedattributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.state
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.task
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.hierarchicalrequirement
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.workspace
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.timeentryitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.testcaseresult
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.weblinkdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.attachmentcontent
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.testfolder
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.attributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.releasecumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.iterationcumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.timeentryvalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.typedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.build
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.project
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.allowedattributevalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.blocker
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.allowedqueryoperator
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.preliminaryestimate
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.release
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.buildmetricdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.recyclebinentry
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.subscription
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.useriterationcapacity
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.builddefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.revisionhistory
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.administratableproject
> rally.domain.v2.x.project.XXXXXXXX.writableproject
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.testcasestep
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.testcase
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitemfeature
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.userprofile
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.buildmetric
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.conversationpost
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.defect
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.defectsuite
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.milestone
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.projectpermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.portfolioiteminitiative
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.user
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.artifactnotification
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.testset
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.tag
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.workspacepermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.scmrepository
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.preference
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitemtheme
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.portfolioitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.revision
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.changeset
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.iteration
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.change
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.workspaceconfiguration
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.attachment
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.scopedattributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.state
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.task
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.hierarchicalrequirement
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.workspace
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.timeentryitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.testcaseresult
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.weblinkdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.attachmentcontent
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.testfolder
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.attributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.releasecumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.iterationcumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.timeentryvalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.typedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.build
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.project
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.allowedattributevalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.blocker
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.allowedqueryoperator
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.preliminaryestimate
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.release
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.buildmetricdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.recyclebinentry
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.subscription
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.useriterationcapacity
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.builddefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.revisionhistory
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.administratableproject
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.XXXXXXXX.writableproject
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.testcasestep
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.testcase
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.portfolioitemfeature
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.userprofile
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.buildmetric
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.conversationpost
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.defect
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.defectsuite
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.milestone
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.projectpermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.portfolioiteminitiative
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.user
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.artifactnotification
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.testset
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.tag
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.workspacepermission
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.scmrepository
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.preference
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.portfolioitemtheme
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.portfolioitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.revision
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.changeset
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.iteration
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.change
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.workspaceconfiguration
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.attachment
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.scopedattributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.state
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.task
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.hierarchicalrequirement
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.workspace
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.timeentryitem
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.testcaseresult
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.weblinkdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.attachmentcontent
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.testfolder
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.attributedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.releasecumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.iterationcumulativeflowdata
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.timeentryvalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.typedefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.build
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.project
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.allowedattributevalue
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.blocker
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.allowedqueryoperator
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.preliminaryestimate
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.release
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.buildmetricdefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.recyclebinentry
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.subscription
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.useriterationcapacity
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.builddefinition
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.revisionhistory
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.administratableproject
> rally.domain.v2.x.workspace.null.writableproject
```

So I know I can request a model of `defectsuite` since they use it internally themselves.

User stories are a bit funky because they map to the `Hierarchical Requirement` type in the API. You can sort of see this from the browser console when logged into Rally:

```
a = Ext4.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store',{
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'hierarchicalrequirement'
});
b = Ext4.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store',{
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'Userstory'
});
a.data.getAt(0).id == b.data.getAt(0).id //true
```

I did a small amount of testing and it looks like they strip spaces from the model names, so this would also work for the `b` variable above:

```
b = Ext4.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store',{
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'User   sto     ry    '
})
```

Comment: Hi I just found something. in my model list there is one called ''portfolioitemproposal", however, this is not recognised by Rally api and I had to use 'portfolioitem/proposal' instead. So not all the model name in the list can be used directly in the storeconfig. Any idea about this?

Comment: Interesting that the models don't match exactly - and that I don't see /proposal in their API docs - but you can see portfolioitem/feature listed in the API: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Comment: That brings me more confusion because I can see PortfolioItem/Proposal  in the web service doc instead of portfolioitem/feature.

Comment: Could it be a custom type that your organization has defined?

Comment: @pherris is right. It is a custom type. Rally allows customization of portfolio item types that inherit from PortfolioItem non-creatable type. Go to  WS API document https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ when logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser  and explore the object model. It is specific to your workspace where you are logged in. You will see your custom fields, and you will see your custom portfolio item types if they exist. PortfolioItem/Feature is a standard one, but PortfolioItem/Proposal is created by your internal Rally administrator.

Comment: that makes sense. I'll talk to our rally admin and see what he does. Many thanks.